# Nextjs button onClick does not work after static export

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, next.js, export

I have a very basic Next.js that works during development. But when I try to static export it with `next build & next export` I can't click on the button anymore. Doing inspection shows that there's no event attached to this button

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I deployed to Netlify and Vercel and it has the same issue, there's no onClick event for button

There are a bunch of ERR 404 in Console https://onmyway133.com/almighty/ so that's suspicious as well

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to open the generated HTML file directly in your browser, and the resources are not loading (relative path issue), see network errors in dev tools. Use some tool like [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) or [`serve`](https://github.com/vercel/serve) to serve the code locally, it should work.

Using serve:

```sh
yarn global add serve # npm install -g serve

yarn next build
yarn next export
yarn serve out # npx serve out #-- if you just want to try
```

---

##### For updated question:

Another alternative is to set [`assetPrefix`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix) (may not work with nested pages):

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = { assetPrefix: './' }; // enforces relative paths
```

This issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2581

---

Also, I am not able to reproduce your particular question:

GitHub: https://github.com/brc-dd/so-68406279
Vercel: https://so-68406279.vercel.app
Netlify: https://stupefied-wright-3d7c4b.netlify.app

This implies there is an issue with your project structure, config or deployment strategy altogether.

Comment: I deployed to Netlify and Vercel and it has the same issue, there's no onClick event for button